# DB visualizer connection issues with the Hive thrift server (Query still running after completion) [HDP 2.6.x]

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, thrift, dbvisualizer

We are using DB visualizer to query Hive database on HDP 2.6.x, we are facing connection related issues with DB visualizer and hive.

DB visualizer does not close the connection with Hive thrift server due to that jobs are always in running state in Hive/Hadoop even after a query is successfully executed and the result set is returned on DB Visualizer and eventually those jobs runs forever and consume all the hadoop resources and rest of the jobs are always in ACCEPTED state.

If you have face similar kind of issue can you please help me on this.

Comment: Did you try with an alternate JDBC driver, i.e. by Cloudera or DataDirect?

Comment: Did you consider just restarting the damn HS2 service every day -- or even setting up HA with ZooKeeper to allow for service "rotation" _(set new svc as default, wait 1h for active connections to drain, restart old, switch back tomorrow)_ -- because that's what I've had to use on HDP, back in 2015 (some OOM bugs linked to connection pools have been corrected since, but...)

Comment: Thanks, will try out your recommendation and update you.